# short often network pauses when 2 routers connected

Tags: networking, router, dns, routing, ethernet

my network looked like that:

```
ISP cable --- ISP modem --- my router --- cable connection to computer 1
                                      \-- wifi connection to computer 2
```

everything worked great. recently my ISP changed his modem to modem/router (2 in 1). no changes were done to my router. so now i have

```
ISP cable - 
           \
            |
 ISP modem and router (2 in 1) --- my router --- cable connection to computer 1
                                             \-- wifi connection to computer 2
```

when i disconnect my router and connect computers directly to ISP modem/router everything works. but i want my router because of QoS and other settings so it looks like in above diagram.

currently everything works but like every ~30mins network pauses (on my both computers) for about 40 seconds. ping hangs, firefox doesn't load new pages but internet radio or shooting games work - even during the pause.

when everything works:

```
mtr -wb google.com
Start: Sun Feb 15 18:56:38 2015
HOST: kibo                                               Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- router.asus.com (192.168.1.1)                       0.0%    10    0.2   0.3   0.2   0.4   0.0
  2.|-- 192.168.0.1                                         0.0%    10    0.7   0.6   0.6   0.7   0.0
  3.|-- xx-xx-xx-xx.dynamic.chello.pl (xx.xx.xx.xx)         0.0%    10   18.1 607.5  13.8 2870. 1021.2
  4.|-- xx-xx-xx-xx.infra.chello.pl (xx.xx.xx.xx)           0.0%    10    8.1   7.9   7.0   9.2   0.3
  ....
```

when there is a problem:

```
mtr -wb google.com
Start: Sun Feb 15 18:48:00 2015
HOST: kibo                          Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- router.asus.com (192.168.1.1)  0.0%    10    0.3   0.3   0.2   0.4   0.0
  2.|-- ???                           100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

so what may be causing those pauses? how to diagnose it and solve?

Comment: 'solve' == remove 2nd router, or disable 1st one. Double NAT is not going to be fun to use.

Comment: What happens if you put router 1 in bridge mode?